# [ROS + Gazebo + SLAM] How to get specific goal from map?

Tags: slam, gazebo, navigation, hokuyo, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,

I have set up navigation stack for my mobile robot. Now I want to get specific goal from map (or LaserScan data) based on the shape of scan (let's say I have model of rack with multiple channel sections as it's legs and I want the robot to move near one of this legs). Anybody has idea how to approach this topic?

Thank you for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/402046/%5Bros-+-gazebo-+-slam%5D-how-to-get-specific-goal-from-map?/) by [marshall107](https://answers.ros.org/users/91143/marshall107/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-06-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

PCL + RANSAC mentioned there could be a good start:

- https://discourse.ros.org/t/how-to-identify-3d-shapes-rectangle-circle-and-square-using-ros-laser-scan-data/4790
- https://pointclouds.org/ (PCL)
- https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/latest/random_sample_consensus.html (RANSAC)
- https://answers.ros.org/question/229784/detecting-spheres-using-ransac-in-pcl/ (Sphere detection using RANSAC)

You would detect the configuration and position of the spheres/lines/planes and then use this info to move the robot where you wanted.

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1